# How do I host (non-local host) MySQL for JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

sorry if this is a super easy question, but I have been googling a lot and I have failed to get a result.

I am looking for a way that I can either purchase or host so that I and others can connect remotely.

I have all my code working locally, but I would just like to know how to host for others to join.

Comment: This question attracts opinionated answers - hence downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to provide a MySQL server instance that's accessible over the public internet.

For this to be secure, you'll need to use transport layer security (TLS) for the connections from JDBC clients to the server. Even when you do this you'll need to be vigilant about the security of your database.

If your users' data is sensitive, or needs protection against cybercriminals, this is probably a bad idea. (Sensitive data: personally identifiable information, payment/credit card data, health data, personal financial data). It's much safer to put MySQL instances behind solid firewalls, and use web services and/or web sites to grant access to the public internet.

You could run a virtual machine instance on AWS or some other cloud service provider, and put MySQL on it. AWS also offers a Relational Database managed service you could use.

You could use a GoDaddy style service, and enable remote access to your own MySQL instance on that service.

You could put a MySQL instance on a machine in the DMZ -- the publicly visible segment -- of your home or office network.  Most home and small-office routers allow a particular port on a particular machine to be made visible to the public network.

Be careful, k?

Comment: Thanks. I am very new to programming, I am just making simple games and like chatting kinda stuff. No security is really needed.

Comment: "no security is really needed."  That is simply not true. Unless you NEVER EVER EVEN ONCE access your personal bank account or email account from the same machine you'll put on the network. Please, don't underestimate cybercriminals.

Comment: I thought you mean't just the server info needs to be safe, I know what you mean now. Thank you.